# AS3 default values as Class in Function Parameter

Tags: actionscript

How can I assign a default value for a function parameter of type Class in Action script 3

```
    public function foo(param:Class = ????? )
    {

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, but here's a workaround to achieve the same effect:

```
public function foo(param:Class = null ):void
{
    if(!param) 
    {
        // this'll be your default class
        param = MyClass;
    }
    //  here you can do: var bar:* = new param();
}
```

Comment: You can also add an undefined acceptance of variables to your function and use it as an array.

    public function foo( ...args ):void
    {
        trace ( args );
    }